# Query to merge multiple rows into into distinct rows with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't consider myself a complete SQL novice, but I have been staring at this problem for two days now, on and off, and I am beginning to think maybe I am!

Using the following two tables:

```
ID    Category
1     Animal
2     Color
3     Sport

Name    ID    Value
Fred    1     Cat
Fred    2     Blue
Fred    3     Football
Sally   1     Dog
Sally   3     Jogging
James   2     Green
Anne    3     Swimming
```

I have been unable to find any combination of group by, sub-query, union, cte or pivot commands that will merge the multiple rows returned from an  ‘(ID =  1 or ID = 2)’ query into a distinct rows with multiple columns.

E.G.:

```
where (ID=1 or ID=2)

Name     Animal    Color
Fred     Cat       Blue
Sally    Dog       NULL
James    NULL      Green
```

Can anyone please advise me if there is an efficient SQL solution to this or am I wasting my time on something that should be handled by code in the report?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes the PIVOT syntax

```
SELECT Name,[1] as Animal, [2] as Color
FROM
(SELECT Name,Id,Value
    FROM Table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MIN(Value)
FOR Id IN ([1], [2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Wow! I suspected there had to be a pivot but my inelegant attempts fell flat. I love the simplicity in this approach!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with:

```
Select a.Name as Name, a.Value as Animal, c.Value as Color
 FROM
     (SELECT Name, Value 
        FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 
             ON table2.ID = table1.ID AND table2.ID =1) as a 
     LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT Name, Value 
        FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 
          ON table2.ID = table1.ID AND table2.ID =2) as c
     ON a.Name = c.Name
UNION
Select c.Name as Name, a.Value as Animal, c.Value as Color
 FROM
     (SELECT Name, Value 
        FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 
             ON table2.ID = table1.ID AND table2.ID =1) as a 
     RIGHT JOIN 
     (SELECT Name, Value 
        FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 
          ON table2.ID = table1.ID AND table2.ID =2) as c
     ON a.Name = c.Name
```

The table 2 is strange and it's not very well designed.

Comment: Thanks Bora, I was just about to reply that I had already tried your first suggestion when I notice you chaged it wo one that seems to work very well indeed!

Comment: Also, you are right about table 2, I don’t like the way it works, but I have inherited it and it isn’t in my power to change at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH filtered_table AS (
  SELECT Name, ID, Value
  FROM table2
  WHERE ID IN (1, 2)
)
SELECT
  t2.Name,
  Animal = MAX(CASE t1.ID WHEN 1 THEN ft.Value END),
  Color  = MAX(CASE t1.ID WHEN 2 THEN ft.Value END)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM filtered_table) t2
  INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.ID IN (1, 2)
  LEFT JOIN filtered_table ft ON t2.Name = ft.Name AND t1.ID = ft.ID
GROUP BY t2.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I did investigate using CTEs, but my lack of experience e with them meant I had no success.  Your query looks interesting and parses correctly against the scratch database I created for this example, but execution fails with "Invalid object name 'filtered_table2'". Any suggestions?

Comment: None apart from yours truly having got two left hands. Sorry, I meant `filtered_table` (without `2`). Fixed.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but when I removed the ‘2’ things got worse with multiple ‘invalid column name’ complaints relating to the id and value fields. I can follow the query logically, but my lack of CTE experience is the real issue.

Comment: @somnolent: But of course! How could they not go worse since I also forgot to add `GROUP BY`? And also some table aliases. My bad again, will you ever forgive me? (Fixed the issue.)

Comment: Thanks again Andriy, what's to forgive? you are giving up your time to help me and it now works great thanks!