# Select rows from 3 tables and display in 1 row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to select Building, RoomMin, and RoomMax from these 3 tables and present them in separate fields.

Tables

```
GenericTableDataID  Building
17                  B1
18                  B1
20                  B1

RoomMinDataID   RoomMin
17              200
20              100

RoomMaxDataID   RoomMax
17              299
18              399
```

Desired Result

```
GenericTableDataID  Building    RoomMin RoomMax
17                  B1          200     299
```

Failed Attempt:

```
SELECT GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID, ValueString AS Building, ValueString AS RoomMin, ValueString AS RoomMax
FROM GenericTableData INNER JOIN
    GenericTableDataField ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID = GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDataID INNER JOIN
    GenericTableDefinition ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID INNER JOIN
    GenericTableDefinitionField ON GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
    GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionID
WHERE GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = 13 -- Access Level
    AND GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID IN (  -- RoomMin
        SELECT GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID
        FROM GenericTableData INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDataField ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID = GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDataID INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDefinition ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDefinitionField ON GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
            GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionID
        WHERE ValueInteger <= '235'
            AND GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID IN ( -- List of data that are associated with B1
                SELECT GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID
                FROM GenericTableData INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDataField ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID = GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDataID INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDefinition ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDefinitionField ON GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
                    GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionID
                WHERE ValueString LIKE 'B1'
            )
            AND GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = 11          
    )
    AND GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID IN (  -- RoomMax
        SELECT GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID
        FROM GenericTableData INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDataField ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID = GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDataID INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDefinition ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID INNER JOIN
            GenericTableDefinitionField ON GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
            GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionID
        WHERE ValueInteger >= '235'
            AND GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID IN ( -- List of data that are associated with B1
                SELECT GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID
                FROM GenericTableData INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDataField ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDataID = GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDataID INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDefinition ON GenericTableData.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID INNER JOIN
                    GenericTableDefinitionField ON GenericTableDataField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
                    GenericTableDefinition.GenericTableDefinitionID = GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionID
                WHERE ValueString LIKE 'B1'
            )
            AND GenericTableDefinitionField.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = 12
    )
```

My above query doesn't return any rows because I'm trying to search for a specific Building Room Number in the inner WHERE SELECTS.

Comment: And what query have you tried?  You are expected to try not just expect code generation as a service.

Comment: I added my attempt now.  Sorry that I didn't show it earlier.  I was lead to believe I should try coalesce and pivot like from this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014656/query-to-merge-multiple-rows-into-into-distinct-rows-with-multiple-columns.

Thank you to everyone that replied.  I have a good direction to pursue now.  I'm not used to grabbing from multiple tables in this way.  I'll try all of your suggestions and mark one as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.GenericTableDataID, A.Building, B.RoomMin, C.RoomMax
FROM table_1 AS A 
JOIN table_2 AS B ON
    A.GenericTableID = B.RoomMinDataID
JOIN table_3 AS C ON
    A.GenericTableID = C.RoomMaxDataID
WHERE A.GenericTableID = 17
```

`table_1` is the top table in your question, `table_2` is the middle, and `table_3` is the bottom.

Comment: I chose this answer because it has the ID field in the filtering criteria.  Even though I didn't directly say that was what I was looking for.  All the other answers though were helpful and lead me to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT generic.GenericTableId
     , Building
     , RoomMin
     , RoomMax
FROM GenericTableDataId generic
     JOIN RoomMinDataId min_data ON generic.GenericTableDataId = min_data.RoomMinDataId
     JOIN RoomMaxDataId max_data ON generic.GenericTableDataId = max_data.RoomMaxDataId
```

Answer (score 0):

as fellow "gr1zzly be4r" post, you could use JOIN functions and use a few alias

```
SELECT GenericTableDataID,Building,RoomMin,RoomMax 
From table1 
join table2 on
  GenericTableDataID=RoomMinDataID
join table3 on
  RoomMinDataID=RoomMaxDataID
where GenericTableDataID = 17
```

also, another option

```
select GenericTableDataID,Building,RoomMin,RoomMax 
FROM table1,table2,table3
where GenericTableDataID=RoomMinDataID and RoomMinDataID=RoomMaxDataID and GenericTableDataID=17
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Data.GenericTableDataID AS AccessLevelID, TDRR.Building, TDRR.RoomMin, LTDRR.RoomMax, DataF.ValueString AS AccessLevel
FROM GenericTableData Data
    INNER JOIN GenericTableDataField DataF ON Data.GenericTableDataID = DataF.GenericTableDataID
    INNER JOIN GenericTableDefinition Def ON Data.GenericTableDefinitionID = Def.GenericTableDefinitionID
    INNER JOIN GenericTableDefinitionField DefF ON DataF.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = DefF.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID AND 
        Def.GenericTableDefinitionID = DefF.GenericTableDefinitionID
    INNER JOIN TableDataRoomRanges TDRR ON TDRR.BuildingDataID = Data.GenericTableDataID
WHERE DefF.GenericTableDefinitionFieldID = 13

-- Query for TableDataRoomRanges view
SELECT TableDataBuildings.BuildingDataID, TableDataBuildings.Building, TableDataRoomMin.RoomMin, TableDataRoomMax.RoomMax
FROM 
    TableDataBuildings
INNER JOIN
    TableDataRoomMin ON TableDataBuildings.BuildingDataID = TableDataRoomMin.RoomMinDataID
INNER JOIN
    TableDataRoomMax ON TableDataBuildings.BuildingDataID = TableDataRoomMax.RoomMaxDataID
```

Comment: What happens if you don't use distinct?

Comment: If I don't use distinct, I could get duplicate rows.

Comment: really? I would never have guessed. The point of my question is that `select distinct` often isn't a good solution when used over multiple joins and that you may need to treat one or or of those tables by subquery so that you don't need to use it.   http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx